# how to convert this declaration of variables Oracle to Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, variables, converters

this is the code in Oracle:

```
  pUsuario             IN     SAV_CAMPANAS_ENCA.USUARIO_CREA%TYPE,
  pCodTipo             IN     SAV_TIPOS_CAMPANA.COD_TIPO%TYPE,
  pCantidadRegistros   IN     SAV_CAMPANAS_ENCA.CANTIDAD_REGISTROS%TYPE,
  pPrograma            IN     SAV_CAMPANAS_ENCA.PROGRAMA%TYPE,
  pCodPais             IN     SAV_PAIS.COD_PAIS%TYPE,
  pNumeroIntentos      IN     SAV_CAMPANAS_ENCA.MAXIMO_INTENTOS%TYPE,
```

Comment: That's not possible in SQL Server as far as I know

Comment: Seriously, no there is something?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no equivalent for `%TYPE` in T-SQL, but then I haven't used SQL Server for along time (let alone stored procedures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have anchored type declarations-- you can't do the equivalent of `<<table>>.<<column>>%TYPE`.  You'd need to determine the actual data types of the underlying columns and use those.  Of course, that means that if you change the data type of some column, you'd need to go through your code to change the data type of the variables that need to reference that column.